# Связь между частями бессоюзного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, бсп

*Продажи упали на 23%, расходы увеличились на 15%, поэтому нам нужно произвести сокращение зарплат.*

Ясно ли, что последняя часть относится и к первой и ко второй, или это нужно как-то обозначить, например тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Продажи упали на 23%, расходы увеличились на 15%, поэтому нам нужно произвести сокращение зарплат.**

Это БСП, между первыми двумя предложениями **однородные перечислительные** отношения, что следует из одинаковой формы прошедшего времени у глаголов.

В третьем предложении используется форма настоящего времени для сказуемого и есть местоименное наречие ***поэтому*** со значением следствия.

Эти факты  указывают на то, что третье предложение обозначает **общее следствие** по отношению к первым двум предложениям.

Следует отметить, что неоднородные отношения выражены с помощью структурных элементов (наречия и измененной формы глагола), в то время как интонация перечислительная, что соответствует **постановке запятых.**

Comment: А где вы здесь увидели форму будущего времени?

Comment: То есть как таковых правил соотнесения нет, есть правила логики и чувство языка?

Comment: Время исправлено, а о правилах соотнесения ничего не могу сказать. Я не слышала про такие правила в пунктуации.